# jquery mobile iscrollview on a long list with images

Tags: jquery-mobile-listview, iscrollview

My app has a long listview of a maximum of 99 entries. Each one has an image. A top and bottom fixed bars.

I decided against using pull to refresh since the display got very slow and displayed empty items for a second before showing them.

I face 2 problems :

- the list is quite slow. Especially on the first scroll. It is much faster once I have scrolled to the bottom and come back to the top but I can't expect the users to do that each time
- Each item has an image (with a default background image). Sometimes, the browser doesn't wait for long enough and shows a broken image (with a ?) instead of waiting for the image to show.

How can I increase the waiting time before a (?) shows up ? Is it possible to tell iscrollview to only fetch images on the part of the list currently displayed ? Is it possible to not display the (?) at all and if the image cannot show up, just keep the background image ?

PS: I use JQM 1.3.1 and Iscrollview 1.3.1

Thank you.

Comment: OK. The solution for the broken images is here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92720/jquery-javascript-to-replace-broken-images